# how to load xml file into collection c# windows forms

Tags: c#

how to load xml into collection and view in datagrid. 
[My Xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tw9CG.png)

Add new record in xml

```
private void addToXml(bool value)
{
    List<klientprywatny> klienci = new List<klientprywatny>();
    klienci.Add(new klientprywatny() { Imie = txtImie.Text, Nazwisko = txtNazwisko.Text, miasto = txtMiasto.Text, ulica = txtUlica.Text,
        kodpocztowy = txtKodPocztowy.Text, telefon = txtTelefon.Text, email = txtEmail.Text, numer = txtNumer.Text });


    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("Osoby.xml");
    var osoba =
      from klient in klienci
      orderby klient.Nazwisko, klient.Imie
      select new XElement("osoba",
           new XElement("imie", klient.Imie),
                new XElement("nazwisko", klient.Nazwisko),
                new XElement("miasto", klient.miasto),
                new XElement("ulica", klient.ulica),
                new XElement("kodpocztowy", klient.kodpocztowy),
                new XElement("telefon", klient.telefon),
                new XElement("email", klient.email),
                new XElement("numer", klient.numer)
        );

    doc.Root.Element("prywatni").Add(osoba);
    doc.Save("Osoby.xml");

}
```

I tried 
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load("Osoby.xml");

```
        List<klientprywatny> klienci = (
            from osoba in xml.Root.Elements("osoba")
            select new osoba(
                osoba.Element("imie").Value,
                osoba.Element("nazwisko").Value,
                osoba.Element("miasto").Value,
                osoba.Element("ulica").Value,
                osoba.Element("kodpocztowy").Value,
                osoba.Element("telefon").Value,
                osoba.Element("email").Value,
                osoba.Element("numer").Value
                )
            ).ToList<klientprywatny>();
```

but it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the elements from XML to your list as follows:

```
IEnumerable<osoba> result = from c in xml.Descendants("osoba")
                            select new osoba()
                            {
                              Imie = (string)c.Element("imie").Value,
                              Nazwisko = (string)c.Element("nazwisko").Value,
                              miasto = (string)c.Element("miasto").Value,
                              ulica = (string)c.Element("ulicia").Value,
                              kodpocztowy = (string)c.Element("kodpocztowy").Value,
                              email = (string)c.Element("telefon").Value,
                              numer = (string)c.Element("email").Value,
                              telefon = (string)c.Element("numer").Value,
                             };
```

I've tested this code, it works perfectly.

Hope it helps.

Comment: How to bind this collection from datagrindview to allow edit. Next step is to save back to my xml file.